# ruby savon - only xsd no wsdl

Tags: ruby, xsd, wsdl, savon

i've successfully used savon with a site that has wsdl but now i have a site that only supplies the xsd so i can't execute

```
client = Savon.client("http://service.example.com?wsdl")
```

Can savon import and use for data extraction? I think there would be a way by faking some headers but i'm not sure.

for reference the xsd is here http://api.parature.com/schema/xsd/Retrieve-Ticket.xsd

Charles

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question seems a bit vague as to what exactly you want help with. For example, what is *data extraction*? *Faking headers*? Please help us understand your problem.

Comment: sorry (need to move from head to paper..)- data extraction, i meant calling the functions such as get_ticket and then being able to have the data structures as per wsdl (or xsd in this case). faking the headers - not sure what else to call it but basically adding endpoints and namespace (this part i'm really not sure - if all i have is xsd what do i need to set up in savon so i can use the xsd as i did when i had a site with full wsdl)

Comment: also if / when i can get this to work i figure i'll send to rubii for possible use as example in docs - not sure how big a use case this is

Answer (score 1):

Savon is specifically a soap client, hence the need for a [wsdl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSDL). Although soap is expressed  in xml and wsdl is part xsd, the oposite is not true, as [schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) is not a web service definition. Long and short, you are out of luck there, Savon will be of no use. No matter how much you try and hack at it, you're beating a dead horse.

The closest satisfying compromise I can suggest is [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/), used by Savon, which is quite capable of [dealing with the xsd/xml](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Schema.html) interface you are faced with now, all on its own.

nJoy!